Timer Continues in Background but Does Not Update Backend Data - PHP Session and AJAX Issue
I have developed a PHP application where a timer on a web page continues to run even when the browser tab is in the background, particularly on mobile devices. The timer updates visually, but I'm encountering issues with reliably storing the elapsed time data into the backend database.
Key Points:
Frontend: The application uses PHP for server-side logic and includes a JavaScript timer script to display and update elapsed time (HH:MM:SS format).
Backend: I've implemented an AJAX function to send elapsed time data to updateElapsedTime.php for storage in MySQL.
Issue: Despite the timer running in the background, the data doesn't consistently update in the database, especially after extended periods of inactivity.
Setup:
Environment: Hosted on InfinityFree.
Session Handling: PHP sessions are managed to authenticate users (session_start()).
AJAX Setup: Utilizes fetch() API in JavaScript to send JSON data to the backend.
ajax code :
function updateElapsedTime() {
    let timerValue = document.getElementById('display').innerText;
    let startTime = getCookie('startTime');
    let logoutTime = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1]; // Current time in ISO format

    fetch('updateElapsedTime.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            elapsedTime: timerValue, 
            startTime: startTime,
            logoutTime: logoutTime
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('ElapsedTime updated in database:', data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error updating elapsedTime:', error));
}

updateElapsedTime.php:
<?php
include("connection.php");
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $elapsedTime = $data['elapsedTime'];
    $startTime = $data['startTime'];
    $logoutTime = $data['logoutTime'];
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d'); 

    // Escape variables to prevent SQL injection
    $elapsedTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $elapsedTime);
    $startTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $startTime);
    $logoutTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $logoutTime);

    // Example query to update elapsed time in database
    $updateSql = "UPDATE stopwatch_data 
                  SET elapsedTime = '$elapsedTime',
                      logoutTime = '$logoutTime'
                  WHERE start_date = '$startDate' 
                  AND employee_id = {$_SESSION['uid']}";

    if ($con->query($updateSql) === TRUE) {
        echo json_encode(["success" => true]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["success" => false, "message" => "Error updating elapsed time: " . $con->error]);
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(["success" => false, "message" => "Invalid request method"]);
}

$con->close();
?>

**I have tried **
Session Handling: Ensured PHP sessions are properly initialized (session_start()) and configured session settings (ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 28800); session_set_cookie_params(28800);) to handle extended session lifetimes (8 hours).
AJAX Implementation: Implemented fetch() API in JavaScript to send JSON data to updateElapsedTime.php. Verified that data (elapsedTime, startTime, logoutTime) is correctly formatted and sent via POST request.
Backend PHP Script: Developed updateElapsedTime.php to receive JSON data, decode it, sanitize inputs (mysqli_real_escape_string()), and construct SQL queries to update the elapsedTime and logoutTime in the MySQL database.
Expected Outcome:
I expected the timer's elapsed time data to consistently update and store in the MySQL database, even when the browser tab is in the background. The goal is to ensure that the timer's data integrity is maintained, reflecting accurate elapsed time for each user session.

I noticed you don't store $startTime, why is it there? You should probably check the value of $_SESSION['uid']. For instance, you could set a variable in your Javascript with this value and add it to the fetch body. In PHP you can then check if it still matches the value in the session.

Please do some debugging to establish if the issue is on the client side, server side or in the database layer. Remove the irrelevant code and tags.
